# SELECT with comma separation in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
--Create/Populate [#Filters]:
if object_id('tempdb..[#Filters]','U') is not null drop table [#Filters]
go
create table [#Filters]
(
 [filterid] int
 ,[filtertype] varchar(50)
 ,[filtername] varchar(50)
 ,[filtercriteria] nvcarchar(max)
)
go
set nocount on
insert [#Filters] select 1, 'Worklist', 'WL1', 'ID_SlotAssignmentFolder=1'
insert [#Filters] select 2, 'Worklist', 'WL2', 'ID_SlotAssignmentFolder=2'
insert [#Filters] select 3, 'Worklist', 'WL3', 'ID_SlotAssignmentFolder=3'
insert [#Filters] select 4, 'Filter', 'Filter1', 'filter_after_hours_offset=0,time_of_day_begin=00:00,worklistKey=1'
insert [#Filters] select 5, 'Filter', 'Filter2', 'filter_after_hours_offset=0,time_of_day_begin=00:00,worklistKey=1,worklistKey=2'
insert [#Filters] select 6, 'Filter', 'Filter3', 'filter_after_hours_offset=0,time_of_day_begin=00:00,worklistKey=2'
go
--select * from [#Filters]
```

I did not build this table, I am just trying to query from it.

I have a table called Filters.  It contains two types, Filters and Worklists.  Filters reference Worklists in the 'filtercriteria' column.

In the above example, Filter1 references WL1, Filter2 references WL1 and WL2, and Filter3 references WL2.

I need a query that will search the filters to ensure all of the Worklists are being referenced.  For example, I want to be able to search the above table and for it to return WL3 because WL3 is not referenced in any of the filters.

There is other information in the filtercriteria column, so I'm not sure how to strip out everything except for the worklistKey info, and with that returned, just search for Worklists that aren't referenced in any Filter.

Comment: So you need to select where the filtertype is 'filter' and check for all the numbers next to 'worklistkey=' and there can be multiples in a given row? Then take a distinct list of those numbers and compare it to the numbers that appear next to 'WL'  in filtername where the filtetype is 'worklist'?

Comment: Correct.  A Filter can have many worklistKey references, or even none.

Comment: Are the worklistkeys always referencing the filterid like in your example? Ie, it says 'worklistKey=2' but is that actually meaning 'filterid = 2'?

Comment: Yes, worklistKey=2 is always filterid=2

Comment: That's nice, so you don't have to parse the numbers from 'WL1', just need to parse the numbers from the filter records.

Comment: I still haven't figured out a way to do it.  I wish I could pull the filtercriteria out to something like C# to parse through the results then do another SELECT where the filerid does not equal what I parse out, but my access to the database is SQL only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use XML functionality to parse a delimited field into multiple rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))),',','') AS filters
FROM
    (SELECT filterid,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(filtercriteria,'worklistKey=','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
     FROM   #Filters
     WHERE filtertype = 'Filter'
    )t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))),',','')) = 1
```

In this case we use 'worklistKey=' as the delimiter to parse on, and use an `ISNUMERIC()` check to filter out the non-numbers (rows that don't have a worklistKey).

This gets you the distinct list of Worklists referenced by Filters, you'll have to left-join from a list of all filters to finish this out. Might get messy if the reality is much different from your sample.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  In my reality, filterid is actually a uniqueidentifier instead of an int, so I'm having trouble replacing the ISNUMERIC line with something else.

Comment: You don't need the filter, they filtered rows would never join to a uniqueidentifier, the values that we're filtering are  like `filter_after_hours_offset=0time_of_day_begin=00:00`.